# gradle buid failed with Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I use gradle -s build to trace this eroor and get below trace log

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.DependencyChecker.getApiLevelFromMavenArtifact(DependencyChecker.groovy:99)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.DependencyChecker.excluded(DependencyChecker.groovy:38)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.DependencyChecker$excluded.call(Unknown Source)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.addDependency(BasePlugin.groovy:3399)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_addDependency_closure191.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:3417)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.addDependency(BasePlugin.groovy:3415)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_resolveDependencyForConfig_closure187.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:3273)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencyForConfig(BasePlugin.groovy:3271)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.this$2$resolveDependencyForConfig(BasePlugin.groovy)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$this$2$resolveDependencyForConfig$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencies(BasePlugin.groovy:3174)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:464)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:550)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:326)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:212)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$createAndroidTasks.call(Unknown Source)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:463)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure9.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:408)
at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
... 28 more
```

My project depend on a maven project which have a dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My question is why in getApiLevelFromMavenArtifact(), the id.version is null?

Comment: I think it's because the version `4.4.2` does not exist, or at least, is not handled by the `getApiLevelFromMavenArtifact`. If you go [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/68794758/), and scroll to the bottom of the page, you can see the latest version which will return an id is `4.1.1.4`. So I would try putting this value as version, instead of `4.4.2`.

Comment: Do u means I could not use 4.4.2 on my maven library project? The 4.4.2 is exist, and I have to use JavascriptInterface which in API 21

Comment: Of course you can use the version `4.4.2`; actually you don't have a choice, since the version `4.1.1.4` supports  API 15. However, you can not use the method `getApiLevelFromMavenArtifact`, because it will return null, since it doesn't handle the version `4.4.2`. By the way, I think it's weird the method doesn't return -1 when a version is not handled.

Comment: Could you post the code that crashes?

Comment: Which code ? build.gradle ? I trace the source code from code.google.com to github, and find that this development of this plugin has been discontinued.Google has created their own Android development toolchain based on Gradle, which supercedes this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no `'com.google.android:android:4.4.2'` in [mavenCenter](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.android%22%20AND%20a%3A%22android%22) or [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.android%3Aandroid/view).

And as far as I guess, you're developing an Android project using Gradle. If it's right, you need not to write a `dependencies` about `android.jar` by yourself.

You should write `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` at the beginning of the file called `build.gradle`. And you just need to tell gradle which version do you want. Such as,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    minSdkVersion 14
}
```

And if I guess wrong, maybe you can only use the version about android.jar provided by `jCenter` and `mavenCenter`.